# How to know which Dockerfile was used to generate hub image

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am facing an issue when I try to create a custom image containing tensorflow. But when I use the [official repositories](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/) I did not see that problem. Then I am trying to know which Docker file from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles was used to generate the [Docker.hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/) image. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Please provide the docker file or at least the `FROM` parameter, so we can know the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `[docker image inspect][1]` to get further information about an image's layers and how it was built locally.

On docker hub if you click on the tags tab, you can click on any image, and it will show you that info in  a very nice annotation of that image's layers. Next to the dockerfile.